# Joining 2 Strings

Tags: javascript, string

I have a data set of cities and states, which looks like (city:state, city:state, etc). I'm trying to get an output of (SPAN: city:state, SPAN: city:state, etc). Basically, just adding "SPAN: " to each city:state item.

I thought this would give me the answer...

```
function test(link_list) {
  for(var i in link_list)
    console.log("SPAN:", link_list[i]);
}
test("123");;
```

which yields "SPAN: 1, SPAN: 2, SPAN: 3"

However, when replacing "123" with my data (cleveland:ohio), I'm getting the output...

```
SPAN: c
SPAN: l
SPAN: e
SPAN: v
SPAN: e
SPAN: l
SPAN: a
SPAN: n
SPAN: d
SPAN: :
SPAN: o
SPAN: h
SPAN: i
SPAN: o
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Post your input data. Is it an array?

Comment: Definitely - input data looks like a String.

Comment: You know how to format code in a question. You also know how to express a coding problem in a very objective manner. That makes you a better programmer than dozens of people who wander around here everyday. You are not a noob. Keep coding and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the opportunity to change how the data is passed to you, you should put each `city:state` into an array like @Alex Linte posted in his answer.

If that is not the case, then you need to look at the string and decide how to split it so you can loop over each `city:state` group.

You really should give us an exact string of what the data looks like. But if its like i expect from your question, it would be something like this.

```
var input = 'cleveland:ohio, san diego:ca, los angeles:ca';
```

If that is the case you just need to split the string up on `,` then loop over that. Here is the code.

```
var input = 'cleveland:ohio, san diego:ca, los angeles:ca';

function test( link_list ) {
    var linkArr = link_list.split( ', ' );
    for ( var i in linkArr ) {
        console.log( 'SPAN:', linkArr[i] );
    }
}

test( input );
```

EDIT: I forgot to tell you *why* your other answer was wrong. When you loop over a string like you were, it basically treats the string like an array, and each part of that array is one character of the string. That's why it posted the output like you noted.

Cheers and keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

Pass `cleveland:ohio` as an array like:

```
test(['cleveland:ohio']);
```

The following code:

```
test(['cleveland:ohio','newyork:newyork']);
```

should output:

```
SPAN: cleveland:ohio
SPAN: newyork:newyork
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle so you can play with it as it suits you better: http://jsfiddle.net/ggkyfyvu/3/

Considering the input a string:

```
var parseToString = function(input){
    return input.split(", ").map(function(val){
        return "SPAN: " + val + " ";            
    }).join();
};

var parseToArray = function(input){
    return input.split(", ").map(function(val){
        return "SPAN: " + val;            
    });
};

var data = "cleveland:ohio, austin:texas";

var resultString = parseToString(data);
var resultArray = parseToArray(data);

console.log(resultString); // outputs "SPAN:cleveland:ohio,SPAN:austin:texas"
console.log(resultArray); // outputs ["SPAN:cleveland:ohio", "SPAN:austin:texas"]
```

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a very useful function, great for fast array transformations. But it doesn't work in **IE8** and below.

As i use it frequently, i have a script with [polyfills](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill)

If you don't want to use polyfills and you do care about old browsers, just iterate through the array resulted after calling `split(", ")` on your input.

Comment: I like the answer, and a fiddle is always great. But full disclosure on this solution - it will not work in IE 8 and below. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.map

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting lucky with "123" because everything in javascript is an object, so whats really happening is that it treats each letter of the string as a value in `linked_list` and it's splitting it and outputting it with span.

`city:state, city:state` looks like you are getting a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object. If it is json instead of parentheses it should be wrapped in curly brackets `{city:state, city:state}`. If it's not then it should be!

As is, your kinda on the right track but it should look like this:

```
    function test(link_list) {
        for(var i in link_list){
            if(link_list.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                console.log("SPAN:", i, ':', link_list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    test({city:'state', city:'state'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/716dv1gg/

You can read more about JSON and `for...in` loops [here on the MDM website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (which is a great resource use it often).